# Keep getting errors when trying to knit a PDF using R Markdown

Tags: r, rstudio, knitr, r-markdown

**cross-post from /r/RStudio**

Hello everybody,

So I've attempted to troubleshoot this issue for about 4 hours last night with no luck. I've looked through all the similar issues in the RStudio community and attempted all the suggested "fixes", but still haven't been able to get this darn thing to work.

Here is link to view the error I am getting:

> http://www.r-fiddle.org/#/fiddle?id=ofOOEmKH

I'm aware that it says a latex package is missing, but I can assure you it is not. I made sure to reinstall it using the MIKTEX package manager and it's working just fine.

I also attempted to install the latest version of RMarkdown from github using the devtools package.

I also attempted to install R onto a directory without any spaces in the directory name -- nothing.

Can somebody please help me out here!

Comment: you could knit your markdown file as an html output, and then print-save-as-pdf from your browser.... not a solution to the underlying problem, but a way of generating a PDF quickly if that's what you need urgently

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Not urgently needed by any means, but this has been a thorn in my side for the last several months.

To be honest, the LaTeX isn't being parsed properly in HTML either...

Comment: I would recommend just using the full tex distro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For those of you who are having similar issues. I fully uninstalled MIKTEX and reinstalled a complete version of [proTeXt](https://www.tug.org/protext/) (which is basically a full install of MIKTEX plus a LaTeX IDE called TeXstudio) and it fully fixed my issue.

I am now able to compile PDFs through RMarkdown without any issue.

Cheers!